# Mask Fluid ViewHelper to not render it

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

In need to print some HTML code that includes some ViewHelper.
Ist there a way to prevent ViewHelpers from beeing rendered?

Input:

```
<my:printBold>Hello World</my:printBold>
```

Actual Output:

> **Hello World**

Expected Output:

```
<my:printBold>Hello World</my:printBold>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to move your snippet to a partial you could use the following functionality:
https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/blob/2.6.5/examples/Resources/Private/Singles/Passthrough.html

`{parsing off}` will disable the Fluid rendering for the whole file.

Also found an issue regarding this:
https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/issues/346

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that yet. But I don't want to create a partial for every snipped and dynamically I can't pass the value as argument to the partial, because otherwise it will be rendered.